# What is a supertype method?

Tags: java, oop, supertype

I have googled couple of times but still can't understand the supertype method. Can anyone please explain what is this?

Comment: you mean methods of super class

Comment: If I am not wrong then it is the call using `super` to the method of the class which has been extended by another, e.g. `super.onCreate` calls the `onCreate` method of the `Activity class`

Comment: could you elaborate ?

Comment: Are you clear Object Oriented Programming first? If not I suggest starting with that.

Comment: "Supertype method" is not an official term afaik. Can you give more context?

Comment: Supertype is used in JAVA GENERICS.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is a notion of supertype and subtype in OOPS, In java  this kind of relationship is implemented by inheritance i.e. using `extends` keyword:

```
class A {} // super class
class B extends A {} //sub class
```

Any member (fields, methods) declared in super class is to be called supertype.

Therefore in above context if class `A` has method like

```
class A {
   void set()
}
```

Set is supertype method for class `B`.

However, notice that if there is another class say `C`:

```
class C {
    void set()        
}
```

Then `set()` method is **not supertype** for `C` class because there is no relationship between class `A` and class `C` (relationship is created by `extends` keyword, for inheritance).

Comment: Furthermore, an interface is also a supertype of any class that implements it (and of any interface that extends it). That ought to make interface default methods supertype methods as well.

Answer (score 3):

if you are talking about calling a super method, you should try the following

1. Create a class with a method public method e.g. `printSomething()`

   ```
   public void printSomething() {
      System.out.println("hello, I am the first class");
    }
   ```
2. Create a second class which inherites from the first class and override the printSomething method

   ```
   @override
   public void printSomething() {
   super.printSomething();
   }
   ```
3. Write a small programme which call the method `printSomething` of class two and see what will happen

Answer (score 2):

Super at Constructer level

```
class SuperClass
{
    int num=10;
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("Superclass display method");
    }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass
{
    int num=20;

    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("the value of subclass variable name:"+num);
        System.out.println("Subclass display method");
    }

    public void Mymethod()
    {
        super.display();
        System.out.println("the value of superclass variable name:"+super.num);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SubClass obj=new SubClass();
        obj.Mymethod();
        obj.display();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In java every thing are object and a method is also a object of class java.lang.reflect.Method
So the super type of method can be consider as the super class of `java.lang.reflect.Method` that is the `AccessibleObject`.

Answer (score 1):

Super Type and sub type is a property of inheritance i.e for the purpose of re-usability of code. I am giving you example of Super Class and Sub class. For more you can follow [here](http://dotnetminds.com/inheritance-using-c-2/).

using System;

```
namespace MultilevelInheritance
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public float fDis { get; set; }
        public Customer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am a normal customer.");
        }
        public virtual void discount()
        {
            fDis = 0.3F;
            Console.WriteLine("Discount is :{0}", fDis);
        }

    }
    public class SilverCustomer : Customer
    {
        public SilverCustomer()
            : base()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am silver customer.");
        }
        public override void discount()
        {
            fDis = 0.4F;
            Console.WriteLine("Discount is :{0}", fDis);
        }
    }
    class GoldenCustomer : SilverCustomer
    {
        public GoldenCustomer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am Golden customer.");
        }
        public override void discount()
        {
            fDis = 0.6F;
            Console.WriteLine("Discount is :{0}", fDis);
        }

    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MultilevelInheritance
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Customer objCus = new Customer();
            objCus.discount();

            SilverCustomer objSil = new SilverCustomer();
            objSil.discount();

            GoldenCustomer objGold = new GoldenCustomer();
            objGold.discount();


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XOdW.jpg)

Comment: Hi, You seem to be adding a link to a website that has  ads w/o disclosing affiliation. It looks like you are trying to get more views on the site. See [How to not be a spammer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). Note that doing so might increase suspicion among the members of the community that may lead to the suspension of your account. Refer this [meta answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294124/4099593). I am writing this comment to warn you beforehand. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Super is used to invoke parent class Properties
used at 3 levels 
variable constructer and method level

1.Super at Variable

```
class Super
{
    int age;
    Super(int age)
    {
        this.age=age;
    }
        public void getAge()
        {
            System.out.println(age);
        }
}
class Sub extends Super
{
    Sub(int age)
    {
        super(age);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         Super obj=new  Super(24);
         obj.getAge();
    }
}
```