# What is supertype?

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

//star my method lab
public class Method extends JPanel {

//two array lists that I am going to use.
ArrayList<String> english = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> french = new ArrayList<>();

    //bring text file as an array
    public void loadEnglishWords() {
        //input my file
        String filename = "english.txt";
        File f = new File(filename);
        try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
            //scan all array line by line
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = s.nextLine();
                english.add(line);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { //wrong file name makes error massage pop up
            String errorMessage = "Wrong!";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, errorMessage, "Wrong!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }   
    }

    //same array job with English to compare
    public void loadFrenchWords() {
        String filename = "french.txt";
        File f = new File(filename);
        try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = s.nextLine();
                french.add(line);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            String errorMessage = "Wrong!";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, errorMessage, "Wrong!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }   
    }

    //check each line to parallel my arrays to get to same position
    public String lookup(String word){
        for (int i = 0; i < english.size();i++) {
            if (word.equals(english.get(i))) {
                return french.get(i);
            }
        }
        //wrong values in arrays 
        return "No match found";
    }

    //infinite loop to run my program until get the result
    public void mainLoop() {
        while (true) {
            //pop-up box to ask English words
            String tmp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter an English Word!");
            //store the result in variable r
            String r = lookup(tmp);
            String a;
            //
            if (r == ("No match found")) {
                a = "Write a Right Word!";
            } else {
                a = "The French word is : " + r + ". Play agian?";

            }
            //asking want to play more or not
            int result;
            result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,a,"RESULT!",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            //doens't want to play then shut down
            if (result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                break;
            }
        }

    }


    //make all things run in order
    @Override
    public void init() {
        loadEnglishWords();
        loadFrenchWords();
        mainLoop(); 
    }
}
```

//My problem is that everytime I compile this program the error message would be: 
"Method.java:88: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
1 error"

//This program is to translate french words to english words using arraylist
I`m using a .txt file for my set of english and french words and have it run through arraylist to translate

//In my program I need to use a JPanel or pop-up box to ask the user to input the word that they wish to translate

//Please note that I am a beginner with Java, please somebody help me and point out on where I got it wrong so I can change it. Thank you so much!

Comment: `JPanel` doesn't have a `init()` method, so you can't pretend overriding this .

Comment: remove `@Override` from  `public void init()` supertype is the class you extends from. in your case `JPanel`

Comment: The error message says the error is on line 88, which is the @Override annotation like the other guys said.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a supertype method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130067/what-is-a-supertype-method)

Answer (score 1):

What the error is saying is that in line 88, you are using the `@Override` to redefine a method named `init` from parent class `JPanel`. But because `JPanel` is what it is (i.e. a part of Java), it does not have `init` method, you can not redefine it, hence the error. Most likely, you should just remove the `@Override`, which will mean you want to add a new method instead of redefining it.

Inheritance is a mechanism where you take an existing class and modify it according to your needs. In your case, your class is named `Method` and it extends (inherits from) `JPanel`, so `JPanel` is the supertype of your class.

If you're just beginning, go read and educate yourself on object-oriented concepts. There are many tutorials, including [YouTube videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0NPR8GFHNmE). Happy learning!

Comment: Hi! thank you for the response! I tried removing the override, it compiled the file but this is the error now:

Comment: Error: Main method not found in class Method, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Comment: will u please help me? I`m so stressed out with this, I dunno where I should go next

Comment: Try changing `public void init()` to `public static void main(String[] args)`. But I'm only guessing, I don't know in what way your code is supposed to work.

Comment: Thank you for your time. 
I tried doing it but I got 3 errors

Comment: Method.java:90: error: non-static method loadEnglishWords() cannot be referenced from a static context
                loadEnglishWords();
                ^
Method.java:91: error: non-static method loadFrenchWords() cannot be referenced from a static context
                loadFrenchWords();
                ^
Method.java:92: error: non-static method mainLoop() cannot be referenced from a static context
                mainLoop();
                ^
3 errors

Comment: I'd really like to help you, but it doesn't work this way. You should really learn the basics of java programming first.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from what was previously mentioned, you need to change a few things:

`public void init() {` should be `public static void main(String args[]) {`

Then you need to make your methods `static`, i.e.

```
public static void loadEnglishWords() {
```

Also, the `arrayLists` need to also be `static`

And one other thing, you should compare with `.equals()` and not `==`

I've re-written your code slightly and now it should work:

```
static ArrayList<String> english = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> french = new ArrayList<>();

    //bring text file as an array
    public static void loadEnglishWords() {
        //input my file
        try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("english.txt"));
            //scan all array line by line
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = s.next();
                english.add(line);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { //wrong file name makes error massage pop up
            String errorMessage = "Wrong!";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, errorMessage, "Wrong!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    //same array job with English to compare
    public static void loadFrenchWords() {
        try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("french.txt"));
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = s.nextLine();
                french.add(line);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            String errorMessage = "Wrong!";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, errorMessage, "Wrong!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    //check each line to parallel my arrays to get to same position
    public static String lookup(String word) {
        for (int i = 0; i < english.size(); i++) {
            if (word.equals(english.get(i))) {
                return french.get(i);
            }
        }
        //wrong values in arrays 
        return "No match found";
    }

    //infinite loop to run my program until get the result
    public static void mainLoop() {
        while (true) {
            //pop-up box to ask English words
            String tmp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter an English Word!");
            //store the result in variable r
            String r = lookup(tmp);
            String a;
            //
            if (r.equals("No match found")) {
                a = "Write a Right Word!";
            } else {
                a = "The French word is : " + r + ". Play agian?";
            }
            //asking want to play more or not
            int result;
            result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, a, "RESULT!", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            //doens't want to play then shut down
            if (result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    //make all things run in order
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        loadEnglishWords();
        loadFrenchWords();
        mainLoop();
    }
}
```